# Graph theory: The average degree of G is at least k

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph with at least $k+1$ vertices, Suppose that for every two vertices that are not adjacent $u,v$ : $d(u)+d(v) \ge 2k$.
>   Prove or disprove: The average degree of G is at least k.

I think it's true, if all the vertices in G are connected to each other than it's obvious. But if not, I'm not sure how to show it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average degree can be written as
$$ \frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v)=\frac{1}{|V|^2-|V|}\sum_{\substack{(u,v)\in V\times V\\u\neq v}}\frac{\deg(u)+\deg(v)}{2}$$
where the couples $(u,v)$ of non-adjacent vertices contribute with something $\geq k$. So we just have to consider the contribute given by the couples $(u,v)$ of adjacent vertices: every edge gives exactly two of such couples, so the total contribute given by the couples $(u,v)$ of adjacent vertices is:
$$ \sum_{e=(u,v)\in E}\left(\deg(u)+\deg(v)\right)=\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v)^2\geq (k+1)\left(\frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{v\in V}\deg(V)\right)^2 $$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The worst case is so represented by regular graphs, but in such a case the claim is trivial.